# Multiple WP_Query with pagination shows Page/2 content on the remaining pages

Tags: wp-query, pagination, paginate-links, offsets

I have gone through many articles and scrolled through almost all the questions here but couldn't resolve my issue. So I'll explain my scenario in detail

My index.php looks like this which segregates the category/pagination content:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if(is_home() || is_front_page()){ ?>
    <?php get_template_part('templates/content','homepage'); ?>
    <?php } else if (is_home()){ ?>
        <?php get_template_part('templates/content','homepage'); ?> <!-- homepage  -->
    <?php } else if (is_page()){ ?>
        <?php get_template_part('templates/content','static'); ?> <!-- Static pages -->
    <?php } else if (is_single()){ ?>
        <?php get_template_part('templates/content','fullblog'); ?> <!-- Blog Detailed page -->
    <?php } else if (is_paged()){ ?>
        <?php get_template_part('templates/content','paged'); ?> <!-- Paginated content -->
    <?php } else { ?>
        <?php get_template_part('templates/content','blog'); ?> <!-- Category page -->
    <?php } ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Opening any Category menu in my WordPress website, it loads content from `templates/content-blog.php`. Notice the `offset => 4` here and it displays correctly with pagination:

```
<div class="section__one">
    <?php
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'category_name' => $category_name,
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    )); 
    ?>
    <div class="section__list">
        <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h1><?php echo substr(get_the_title(),0,150); ?></h1></a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
        <p><?php __('No News'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php 
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'category_name' => $category_name,
        'offset'      => 4,
        'orderby'     => 'post_date',
        'order'       => 'DESC',
        'post_type'   => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    )); 
?>
<div class="category__posts">
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h3><?php echo substr(get_the_title(),0,95); ?></h3></a>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div class="pagination">
    <?php 
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
        'total'        => $the_query->max_num_pages,
        'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
        'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
        'show_all'     => false,
        'type'         => 'plain',
        'end_size'     => 2,
        'mid_size'     => 1,
        'prev_next'    => true,
        'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Newer Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
        'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Older Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
        'add_args'     => false,
        'add_fragment' => '',
    ) );
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <p><?php __('No News'); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Clicking on any Page/X in the above `templates/content-blog.php`, it now loads content from `templates/content-paged.php`

Whether it's Page/2, Page/3 or Page/X, it shows the same content on every page unless I remove `offset => 9`.

I need the first 9 posts to be removed from Page/2 as it is redundant and then correctly display the posts in the rest on the paginated content. How can I resolve this?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'offset' => 9,
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'paged' => $paged
    ) );
?>
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="pagination">
    <?php 
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
            'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
            'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
            'show_all'     => false,
            'type'         => 'plain',
            'end_size'     => 2,
            'mid_size'     => 1,
            'prev_next'    => true,
            'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Newer Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
            'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Older Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
            'add_args'     => false,
            'add_fragment' => '',
        ) );
    ?>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: WordPress documentation on [pagination parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters) says: **Warning**: *Setting the offset parameter overrides/ignores the paged parameter and breaks pagination.*

Comment: Oh! So is there a solution to reduce the total count of posts offset by `-9`? Something like `'total'        => $the_query->max_num_pages - 9`, may be.

Comment: You shouldn’t be using `new WP_Query` at all, and it’s not clear why you are. If you want to change the number of posts per page you can do that from settings. Template files should use the standard loop to display posts, not a custom query: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#the-loop-in-detail This is the most common mistake I see in Wordpress by far and I don’t know where people are learning it.

Comment: @user3362364 If listed numbers represented query results (without offsets), and 5 results were displayed per page (`posts_per_page`), would the bold numbers indicate the results available to the user via pagination? **1 2 3 4 5** 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 **15 16 17 18 19 20**. Where *page 1* would show **1 2 3 4 5**? *Page 2* would show **15 16 17 18 19**? And, *page 3* would show **20**? Could you please outline an example that demonstrates which results should be skipped and which results shown when viewing page 2?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Standard loop doesn't allow you to show posts the way the design is made by the designer. Category design includes 3 different sections where I have to show top 3 posts in one div segregated by another div with a different content. Then, another div with 1 new posts (4th posts) and the rest at the bottom with pagination. Such a design is not possible without using `WP_Query `and `offset` or am I wrong here?

Comment: @kofeigen As mentioned in the other comment, the first page (content-blog.php) has a div block with the latest 3 posts and another div with 1 post showcasing the 4th post. Then another DIV with the remaining posts 5 posts + pagination. Total post of 9 posts on Page 1 (content-blog.php). Page 2 (content-paged.php) loads 9 posts as set in `Settings > Reading`. However, Page 2/Page 3/PageX shows the same content as Page 2.

Comment: @user3362364 You want: *page 1*: [**1 2 3**] [**4**] [**5 6 7 8 9**]; *page 2*: [**10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18**]; *page 3*: [**19 20**]. So, the separation of results into 3 segments only applies to *page 1*. What happens when WP admin changes *Settings > Reading* to a number like 4? or 5? or 12? Multiple calls to WP\_Query seem unnecessary. Is there a reason you cannot use a counter for page 1 to loop through the standard (Main) loop? Using the (zero-based) counter, you stop at index 2 (the 3rd item) for 1st div, 2nd div is index 3, 3rd div indexes 4 to 8. Page 2+ wouldn't use the counter.

Comment: @kofeigen Thank you for the response. I have [1 2 3] [4] [5 6 7 8 9] on page 1. There are DIVs in between the above wp_query. Then there's [ 10 11 12 13 14] on page 2, [14 15 16 17 18] on page 3 etc. Hence I'm using WP_Query.  Settings > Reading is set to 5. How do I go about using the counter? Any code example?

Comment: The desired outcome is not clear. When *Settings > Reading* is set to 5, *page 1* should look the same as when it is set to 9? *Page 2* and *page 3* are supposed to repeat item **14**? Is *Settings > Reading* ever fully respected? A clearer description illustrated with several examples with different settings for *Settings > Reading* is needed to understand the desired outcome.

Comment: Is this a unique, rigid, one-off design, not meant to be used by anyone outside your organization, and not meant to accommodate changes to *Settings > Reading*? It isn't clear if or how this design should accommodate different *Settings > Reading* values, or if *Settings > Reading* should be ignored completely and assumed to be only the value(s) set by using the WP\_Query parameter *posts_per_page*.